# Unable to do javascript onclick event

Tags: javascript, c#, html

I have loop in c#, the looped contents I am  storing in string.

```
foreach (DataRow drModuleId in dtModuleId.Rows)
{
     strModuleIdHtml = strModuleIdHtml + "<div class='col-md-2 text-center MainModule'><span class='" + drModuleId["FONTAWESOMECLASS"].ToString() + "' style='font-size:35px;'></span><br/><br/><span style='font-size:16px;'>" + drModuleId["TXTLONG"].ToString() + "</span><br/><br/>" +
                       "<div class='text-center'><span class='spanOpen' onclick=" + "jsPopulateControlBoardDetail('" + drModuleId["MODULEID"].ToString() + "'"+","+"'"+ drModuleId["TXTLONG"].ToString() +"')>Open</span></div></div>";
}

ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, this.GetType(), "Key", "<script> jsPopulateModuleId(" + '"' + strModuleIdHtml + '"' + ") </script>", false);
```

When i run the above code, following html controls will be generated.

```
<div class='col-md-2 text-center MainModule'>
        <span class='fas fa-tools' style='font-size:35px;'></span><br/><br/>
        <span style='font-size:16px;'>Common Setting</span><br/><br/>
        <div class='text-center'>
            <span class='spanOpen' onclick=jsPopulateControlBoardDetail('12EA','FIRST')>Open</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class='col-md-2 text-center MainModule'>
        <span class='fas fa-sliders-h' style='font-size:35px;'></span><br/><br/>
        <span style='font-size:16px;'>Default Setting</span><br/><br/>
        <div class='text-center'>
            <span class='spanOpen' onclick=jsPopulateControlBoardDetail('74PL','SECOND')>Open</span>
        </div>
    </div>
```

After the html control generation, when I click on Open I am getting JavaScript syntax error. Not able to recognize where I am missing. this works fine when I pass only one parameter, but it fails with two parameter. Can anyone help me

Comment: `onclick=jsPopulateControlBoardDetail...` is missing quotes.

Comment: `onclick="jsPopulateControlBoardDetail('74PL','SECOND')"` will work better - recommended is to set the values as data-attributes and have an unobtrusive click handler in the head

Comment: Looks like messy quoting, you can check what is actually rendered by viewing the source code in the browser.

Comment: as u mentioned those missing double quotes i cant not generate in c# code behind. as it gives problem with string concatenation.

Comment: Use String.Format or $"" string interpolation.

Comment: Also what is this supposed to accomplish? `" + '"' + ` Or this? `+ "'"+","+"'"+`

Comment: two separate two parameters in JavaScript